Fixing indentation in Visual Studio
Hi all i have an issue with indentation in visual studio. It just doesn't work. After choosing the option to format selection or the document nothing happens. I tried doing it with shortcut Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D and with feature search Ctrl+Q.
No using Tabs is out of the question i don't want to manually add or delete indentations i hundreds lines of code.
This question is about why the functionality in visual studio doesn't work and not the code itself
This is the example code i have issue with:
var imageFormatting = new ImageFormatting
{
        CmyksToEdit = new List<CmykToEdit>()
        {
            new()
            {
            SourceCmykColor = cmyk,
            DestinationCmykColor = new Cmyk
            {
            C = 0.1f,
            ...
            }
            }
        }
};


Is the file open as part of a project/solution. What's the name of the file (including extension)?

Do you want to indent SourceCmykColor = cmyk, DestinationCmykColor = new Cmyk, C = 0.1f...K = 0.1f
these codes two spaces to the right? If I understand correctly, after my test, you only need to position the cursor to the left of them and press Tab key.

Using tabs i out of the question. Imagine i have hundreds of lines to fix. The functionality exists in visual studio but doesn't work for some reason. This is what this question is about

This is indeed an issue. I suggest that you report this issue to DC, where professional engineers will handle this problem for you: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
